# How to place markers in a DataGrid scrollbar

Tags: c#, wpf, scrollbar

I have a DataGrid, on the scrollbar I would like to put a marker that shows what items are selected. How would something like this be accomplished?

Have had a look around for similar questions and tutorials with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion you should create a `ControlTemplate` for the scrollbar, in which the `PART_Track` part should be customized (e.g. by adding small rectangles at the different positions). [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742173%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you can find the default style and template for the ScrollBar.

You also have to add a new [AttachedProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to the `ScrollBar` class, so you have some place to store the positions you would like to mark.

Maybe it is better and easier to [create a custom control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295235.aspx), which is based on the `ScrollBar`, and add the required properties there. You still have to create a custom template for that control of course.

And finally, to apply a custom `ScrollBar` `Style` only to `DataGrids` see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255174/controltemplate-for-scrollbar-apply-only-to-datagrid).

Comment: I have created a custom scrollbar with an ItemsControl in the vertical scrollbar. Now I just trying to figure out the AttachedProperty to store positions. I have created a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24177804/creating-an-attachedproperty-to-hold-positions-for-scrollbar-markers